# How to fix the size of the tables on power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I'm working with some data on a power BI matrix since it allows more dimensions than regular tables. The issue I'm having is that the size of the matrix changes depending on the filters I use.

E.G If I use no filters the matrix have 3 columns and 4 rows:

[image]

But if I select one the filters then I lose one row:

[image]

How Can I fix the size of the matrix and just show empty values if that's the case?

EDIT:

I have uploaded the data I'm using to google drive, it's just few rows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Jqer6ObhpA4OpxY8ymXunMiL4hg4tO8/view?usp=sharing

I'm almost taking the data as it is in the table except for the aggregation function for which I'm using this:

```
%Count = 
    DIVIDE(
        COUNT(Hoja1[score]);
        CALCULATE(COUNT(Hoja1[score]); ALL(Hoja1[score]))
    )
```

EDIT2:

I have added the new table:

[image]

And created the relation:

[image]

But still having the same issue:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Vizualizations pane. In rows, where you have "score", click on a triangle. In a menu that pops up, check "Show items with no data".

[image]

Comment: Empty rows and columns still hide after that.

Comment: Then you should post your data model and formulas.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. You need to create a separate table that should contain just 3 records, describing score types ("bad", "good", "regular"). Connect this new table to the main table using score field. Then use the score list from the new table as matrix rows, not scores from the main table.

Comment: And you might need to create a new table for class (similarly), and base your slicers on it, not on a main table.

Comment: Thanks RADO, I did it but still not getting the expected  results.

Comment: Remove the new slicer ("Score" - it's wrong), and re-create previous slicer ("class").